# Take out a value event.data out of a window.addEventListener (MessageEvent) to execute a new function

Tags: angular, typescript

i am working with angular, and i want to create a linkedin Login API. For that i am opening a new window with window.open to permit to the user to accept or not, and when i have the URI getting back from the success of accepting from Linkedin login, i get back a code with a window.addEventListener - event.data., to the parent window with window.opener.postMessage. The problem is that i dont now how to take this value out of the addeventlistener function, to trigger an other function with this value.

**The component who is initiating on the window popup where we will accept or not the linkedin login autorisation**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from "../../services/auth.service";
import { ActivatedRoute }  from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sign-in',
  templateUrl: './sign-in.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign-in.component.scss']
})
export class SignInComponent implements OnInit {
  private code:string;
  private state:string;

  constructor(
    public auth: AuthService,
    public route:ActivatedRoute
    ) { }


 //on initialisation we get the params and send the message to the addeventlistener of the parent
  ngOnInit() {
    //get param of the uri linkedin specified URL
    this.code = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get("code");
    this.state = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get("state");
    if (this.code !== null){
      const params = window.location.search;
      if (window.opener) {
      //if the params exists then we send the code to the parent window
        if (this.state === this.auth.state)
        // send them to the opener window
        {
          window.opener.postMessage(this.code);
        }//end if

      }//end if

    } else if (window.opener){
      window.opener.postMessage('Autorisation annulé');
    }
    window.close();
  }//end onInit

}//end Class
```

The service where window.open code executed to get back the value from child window to parent window

```js
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import {  HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

    //INTERFACE UTILISATEUR
    import { User } from './user.model';

    import { auth } from 'firebase/app';
    import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
    import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

    import { Observable, of, interval, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
    import { switchMap, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

    @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })

    export class AuthService {

    //PROPERTIES --------------
      user$: Observable<User>;
      state:string = '';
      clientID: String = '';
      keyID: String = '';
      urlLinkedin = `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=${this.clientID}&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/authentification/sign-in&scope=r_liteprofile%20r_emailaddress%20w_member_social&state=${this.state}`;
      windowAttributes:string = "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=520,height=700";
      windowTarget:string = "_blank";
      codeRecup:string;
    //END PROPERTIES --------------

    //CONSTRUCTEUR
      constructor(
        private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
        private afs: AngularFirestore,
        private router: Router,
        private http:HttpClient
      ) {

    //METHODS -------------------------------
     //Linkedin  ---------------------- 
    linkedinSignin(){
        window.open(this.urlLinkedin, this.windowTarget, this.windowAttributes);
        window.addEventListener('message',function(event) {
          if (event.origin !== "http://localhost:4200")
          return;
          console.log(event.data);
        },false);
      }
```

I want to get event.data and use it in an other function that will be executed after the  window.addEventListener

```js
    linkedinGetToken (){
//I need to get event.data on a new function who will trigger after the addeventlistener      
this.codeRecup = event.data;
    }
     //End Linkedin ----------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

i found the answer, thanks to this article found on StackOverflow:
https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/avoiding-anonymous-javascript-functions
The answer is to execute a function outside of the addeventlistener (avoiding anonymous function)

```js
  //Linkedin  ---------------------- 
    linkedinSignin(){
        window.open(this.urlLinkedin, this.windowTarget, this.windowAttributes);
        window.addEventListener('message', this.linkedinGetToken, false);
      }

    linkedinGetToken (event){
      if (event.origin !== "http://localhost:4200")
      return;
      console.log(event.data);
    }
     //End Linkedin ----------------------
```